# If $f$ is entire, has roots at $\pm i$, and is bounded by $M$ on the circle $\{z:|z|=2\}$, then $|f(z)|\leq \frac M3|z^2+1|$ on the disk $B(0;2)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function. Suppose $f$ has roots at $z=\pm i$. If $M=max_{|z|=2}|f(z)|$, then prove that $|f(z)|\leq \frac{M}{3}|z^2+1|$ on $B(0;2)$.

I set $f(z)=(z^2+1)g(z)$ where $g$ is entire and does not vanish at $\pm i$. Then i tried to use the Cauchy's Estimate, but could not prove the bound. Any hint(s) would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What if $f(z)=(z^2+1)^2$?  Then $g$ vanishes at $\pm i$.

Comment: oh i forgot to consider the multiplicity of the given roots.

Comment: That's OK, just remove the part about $g$ not vanishing at $\pm i$.

Comment: Anyway, considering $g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{z^2+1}$ is good. You need to show that $\lvert g(z)\rvert \leqslant \frac{M}{3}$ for $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant 2$. How would you go about that using what you are given?

Comment: @DanielFischer should we evaluate $g$ at $|z|=2$? If yes then why can we do it? Does it assumes any idea of maximum principle?

Comment: What problem could there be evaluating $g$ for $\lvert z\rvert = 2$? The only _possibly_ problematic points are $\pm i$, but one of the assumptions is that they aren't actually problematic. Yes, maximum principle is very often a good idea, here too.

Comment: @DanielFischer thank you for the suggestions.